Brick Texture: feed image texture for tiles
I am a bloody beginner, please bear with me.
I am trying to feed images into the brick texture, as user Carlo provided there Combining image texture and brick texture. But I am not succeeding. It is based on https://blenderartists.org/t/cycles-brick-tricks-0-1/685934
I want recreate those tiles. 
Basically i want to plot this image onto each brick.
This is the are my note groups 
This is the result
Any help is greatly appreciated.
I have managed to do it with a single image. This is how my node group looks like. The panel where i applied the tiles has physical dimensions of 2034mm by 600mm. The tiles are 100mm by 100mm
Therefore, the brick height is 1/6, the width is 1/20.34 the division number are needed for the scale too. I have added a roughness, normal and displacement settings too.

this is how it looks like.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Phrogz I added an image with the tiles that i want to recreate for clarification.

Checking the Brick Trick thread you provided, it seems that a basic way to use this setup with an image texture would look like this:

Note that the brick wight/height needs to be the same ratio as your texture's X/Y resolution, and the texture's scale adjusted. Otherwise, the texture gets deformed and/or truncated. If you use a perfectly square texture, it's really easy to figure out. I think that's the only thing you are missing.
This is the only thing to do in order to get one image into each tile.

That being said, in your example you seem to try to mix two different textures according to Blender's brick texture, I guess so that different tiles get either one or the other texture?
You could try to match the two as close as possible, but since Blender's brick texture outputs tiles of an infinite amount of shades without the two tile color values, your result gives exactly that: a more-or-less strong mix of the two textures at the same time, not "either one or the other".
To get that, you would need a pure black OR white output. I'm not sure how to get one that looks "satisfying", but you can get one by passing your brick texture (with mortar size to zero) through a Math node with the Greater Than mode before going into the mix' factor:

There are definitely ways to get a better looking result, and I guess there are probably nice things that can be done using BrickTricks' cellID output, but I'm not that good at nodes, so I leave it to others, if you are even interested into that part.

Did you use the blend file or install the addon? I am a bloody beginner and not able to rebuild this. Could you please share detailed instructions. Thank you.

I used the addon, just as instructed there. How did you get your uv_map_brick_wall node?

I finally managed to set this up using the node form the addon. I have had to add texture and a mapping node to the uv_map_brick_wall node. I updated the post.

could you show an expanded detail of the "Brick Texture" and the node driving the input?  I get image1 on the brick surface, and image2 for the mortar

Set the mortar to zero, you want only different shades for the tiles.
